# XSLT Wrap Elements in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, siblings

I want to wrap some elements in the following XML using XSLT but I can't make it work as expected:

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2017-04-10T18:28:30">
<qryXMLOrders>
<IteNumGDS7>1</IteNumGDS7>
<GooDesGDS23>Data</GooDesGDS23>
<GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
<NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
<ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
<PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
<ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
<StaValAmoGDI1>13.87</StaValAmoGDI1>
<PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
<PreDocRefAR26>6471</PreDocRefAR26>
<PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
<DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
<DocRefDC23>6471</DocRefDC23>
<DocTypDC21A>Y900</DocTypDC21A>
<DocRefDC23A>-</DocRefDC23A>
<DocTypDC21B>Y922</DocTypDC21B>
<DocRefDC23B>-</DocRefDC23B>
<ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
<TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
<TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
<TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
<NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
<NamCE27>Ruthh</NamCE27>
<StrAndNumCE222>9738 SW 94 Terr</StrAndNumCE222>
<PosCodCE223>33176</PosCodCE223>
<CitCE224>Miami</CitCE224>
<CouCE225>US</CouCE225>
<NADLNGGICE>EN</NADLNGGICE>
<MarNumOfPacGS21>RE11628425179GR</MarNumOfPacGS21>
<KinOfPacGS23>EN</KinOfPacGS23>
<NumOfPacGS24>1</NumOfPacGS24>
<InvoiceDate>2017-04-07T00:00:00</InvoiceDate>
<Order_x0020_ID>1184077028</Order_x0020_ID>
</qryXMLOrders>
</dataroot>
```

so the final XML looks like this:

```
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2017-04-10T18:28:30">
<qryXMLOrders>
<IteNumGDS7>1</IteNumGDS7>
<GooDesGDS23>Data</GooDesGDS23>
<GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
<NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
<ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
<PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
<ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
<StaValAmoGDI1>13.87</StaValAmoGDI1>
<PREADMREFAR2>
<PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
<PreDocRefAR26>6471</PreDocRefAR26>
<PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
</PREADMREFAR2>
<DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
<DocRefDC23>6471</DocRefDC23>
<DocTypDC21A>Y900</DocTypDC21A>
<DocRefDC23A>-</DocRefDC23A>
<DocTypDC21B>Y922</DocTypDC21B>
<DocRefDC23B>-</DocRefDC23B>
<COMCODGODITM>
<ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
<TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
<TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
<TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
<NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
</COMCODGODITM>
<TRACONCE2>
<NamCE27>Ruthh</NamCE27>
<StrAndNumCE222>9738 SW 94 Terr</StrAndNumCE222>
<PosCodCE223>33176</PosCodCE223>
<CitCE224>Miami</CitCE224>
<CouCE225>US</CouCE225>
<NADLNGGICE>EN</NADLNGGICE>
</TRACONCE2>
<PACGS2>
<MarNumOfPacGS21>RE11628425179GR</MarNumOfPacGS21>
<KinOfPacGS23>EN</KinOfPacGS23>
<NumOfPacGS24>1</NumOfPacGS24>
</PACGS2>
<InvoiceDate>2017-04-07T00:00:00</InvoiceDate>
<Order_x0020_ID>1184077028</Order_x0020_ID>
</qryXMLOrders>
</dataroot>
```

I use the following XSLT but with that I have the elements appear twice in the XML, one time unwrapped and then wrapped as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!-- identity rule Copy all elements and attributes from the source to the target-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
<!-- Wrap Element   -->
    <xsl:template match="/dataroot/qryXMLOrders">
    <xsl:copy>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="PreDocTypAR21|ComNomCMD1|NamCE27|MarNumOfPacGS21/preceding-sibling::*"/>

    <PREADMREFAR2>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="PreDocTypAR21|PreDocRefAR26|PreDocCatPREADMREF21"/>
    </PREADMREFAR2>  

    <COMCODGODITM>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ComNomCMD1|TARCodCMD1|TARFirAddCodCMD1|TARSecAddCodCMD1|NAtAddCodCMD1"/>
    </COMCODGODITM>   

    <TRACONCE2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="NamCE27|StrAndNumCE222|PosCodCE223|CitCE224|CouCE225|NADLNGGICE"/>
    </TRACONCE2>

    <PACGS2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MarNumOfPacGS21|KinOfPacGS23|NumOfPacGS24"/>
    </PACGS2>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="PreDocCatPREADMREF21|NAtAddCodCMD1|NADLNGGICE|NumOfPacGS24/following-sibling::*"/>

    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you're going to post a duplicate of [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328721/wrap-elements-in-xml-using-xslt), then please at least have the decency to delete the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `apply-templates` on `MarNumOfPacGS21/preceding-sibling::*`, which contains your basic nodes, same at the end of the `xsl:copy`.

Default template is to copy the node, so if you don't want to loose time changing the XSL logic, just make a template than will skip the unwanted nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- identity rule Copy all elements and attributes from the source to the target-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
    <!-- Wrap Element   -->
    <xsl:template match="/dataroot/qryXMLOrders">
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="PreDocTypAR21|ComNomCMD1|NamCE27|MarNumOfPacGS21/preceding-sibling::*" mode="copy-if-needed"/>

            <PREADMREFAR2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PreDocTypAR21|PreDocRefAR26|PreDocCatPREADMREF21"/>
            </PREADMREFAR2>  

            <COMCODGODITM>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ComNomCMD1|TARCodCMD1|TARFirAddCodCMD1|TARSecAddCodCMD1|NAtAddCodCMD1"/>
            </COMCODGODITM>   

            <TRACONCE2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="NamCE27|StrAndNumCE222|PosCodCE223|CitCE224|CouCE225|NADLNGGICE"/>
            </TRACONCE2>

            <PACGS2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="MarNumOfPacGS21|KinOfPacGS23|NumOfPacGS24"/>
            </PACGS2>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="PreDocCatPREADMREF21|NAtAddCodCMD1|NADLNGGICE|NumOfPacGS24/following-sibling::*" mode="copy-if-needed"/>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="PreDocTypAR21|PreDocRefAR26|PreDocCatPREADMREF21|ComNomCMD1|TARCodCMD1|TARFirAddCodCMD1|TARSecAddCodCMD1|NAtAddCodCMD1|NamCE27|StrAndNumCE222|PosCodCE223|CitCE224|CouCE225|NADLNGGICE|MarNumOfPacGS21|KinOfPacGS23|NumOfPacGS24" mode="copy-if-needed">
        <!-- Do nothing, skip these nodes -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-if-needed">
        <!-- Copy (apply default template) -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Untested, but you should get the idea.